# find loops in Neo4j

Tags: loops, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am following this Course [Graph Analytics With Neo4j](https://www.coursera.org/learn/big-data-graph-analytics/supplement/iPmtZ/basic-queries-in-neo4j-with-cypher-supplementary-resources) to explore Neo4j database. The database is very simple, which contains 11 nodes ('A', 'B','C'...), 14 relationships. I want to find all loops within this Neo4j database. I have used this following query to find the loops containing 'A'.

```
match p=(n)-[*]-(m)
where n.Name = ['A'] and m.Name = ['A']
return EXTRACT(n IN NODES(p)| n.Name) AS Paths, length(p)
order by length(p)
```

The problem is that, within several loops generated from the above query, some nodes has been visited twice, like 'C' in the following loop: ["A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "J", "F", "A"].

Which Filter function I can use to eliminate this. Thank you,

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the Cypher query to load the database?

Comment: I don't know how to create this database using Cypher yet. But here is the link to download the dataset (test.csv) file to generate this database: https://www.coursera.org/learn/big-data-graph-analytics/supplement/AjGE3/download-datasets-used-in-this-graph-analytics-with-neo4j. I will update my post when I know exactly how to use Cypher to generate this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this query should work:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]-(m)
WHERE n.Name = ['A'] and m.Name = ['A']
AND NONE (node IN NODES(p) WHERE SIZE(
                FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE node = x AND x.name <> 'A')
        ) > 1
    )
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(p)| n.Name) AS Paths, length(p)
order by length(p)
```

That is: the query uses the [NONE()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-none), [SIZE()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-size) and [FILTER()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter) functions to guarantee that only paths without repeated nodes will be matched.

Based in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261693/6835358).

Comment: Thank you, @Bruno. Your query will not get any loop, since in every loop, start and end nodes will be the same (in this case: 'A' node).

Comment: Hello @James, you are right! I edit my answer, please try it now! :) Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, @James. If this answer solve your question remember to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/360570) to inform other user that your problem is solved and to help future viewers of this question.